# Problem with underscore character in a citation key

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, underscore

It is a few days I am struggling with this error. It gives this error for a few of my citations. Here is a minimum example

**citations.bib**

```
@InProceedings{Cohn_1995,
  author = {Cohn, a},
  title  ={A hierarchical representation of qualitative shape based on connection and convexity},
  booktitle = {Spatial information theory a theoretical basis for GIS},
  year      = {1995},
  pages     = {311--326}
}
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Suggested packages for algorithm formatting
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
% To solve issue with _ in DOI
\usepackage[strings]{underscore}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{BibTeX in action}
    \author{Martin J. Osborne}
    \date{2008-1-13}
    
    \maketitle
    
    
    % Your main text begins here. 
    \section{Introduction}
    
    Hello \cite{Cohn_1995}
    
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{citations}
    
\end{document}
```

and here is errors I have received. Is there any way to find out what is wrong with my citation?

```
line 25: Missing \endcsname inserted. \bibcite{Cohn_1995}{{1}{1995}{{Cohn}}{{}}}
line 25: Extra \else. \bibcite{Cohn_1995}{{1}{1995}{{Cohn}}{{}}}
line 25: Extra \endcsname. \bibcite{Cohn_1995}{{1}{1995}{{Cohn}}{{}}}
line 25: Extra \else. \bibcite{Cohn_1995}{{1}{1995}{{Cohn}}{{}}}
: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.
: Citation(s) may have changed.
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package is obsolete and deprecated. Don't use it! Instead, use either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I am new with Tex and I was using a journal's template and seems they have not updated their template for years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate cause of the problem you've encountered is the fact that you load the [underscore](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/underscore) package. Loading this package can do weird things when LaTeX comes across unescaped instances of `_` in places such as the argument of `\cite` directives. As you've discoverd, this can happen even if the package is loaded with the `strings` option.

Do you truly need to load the `underscore` package? I've noticed that your code contains the comment "To solve issue with _ in DOI". However, that's *not* really a good reason for loading the underscore package. It would be much more efficient if you loaded the `url` or, even better, the `xurl` package, as most doi-aware bibliography styles (including `plainnat`!) automatically encase the contents of `doi` fields in `\url{...}` wrappers.

In the following example, I've back-filled several missing fields in your bibliographic entry, *including* the `doi` field, which contains an underscore character. Observe (a) that the cite key still contains an underscore character, as does the `doi` field, and (b) that the `xurl` package is loaded. With this setup, underscore characters in doi fields are handled just fine and, as a bonus, you don't have to edit the citation keys.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{citations.bib}
@InProceedings{Cohn_1995,
  author    = {Cohn, A. G.},
  title     = {A hierarchical representation of qualitative shape 
               based on connection and convexity},
  booktitle = {Spatial information theory. A theoretical basis for GIS},
  editor    = {A. U. Frank and W. Kuhn},
  year      = {1995},
  pages     = {311--326},
  series    = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  volume    = 988,
  doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-60392-1_20},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib} % or: \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new 
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
%%\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} % not needed if 'xurl' package is loaded

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{Cohn_1995}
\bibliography{citations} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue is with citation key. I should avoid using `_` in the keys

From Comments:

`The presence of an underscore character in the citation key is not the direct cause of the problem. Instead, the cause is the underscore package, which -- even when loaded with the strings package option -- can do weird things when LaTeX comes across unescaped instances of _.`

Comment: The presence of an underscore character in the citation key is **not** the direct cause of the problem. Instead, the cause is the [underscore package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/underscore), which -- even when loaded with the `strings` package option -- can do weird things when LaTeX comes across unescaped instances of `_`. Do you truly need to load the `underscore` package? I've noticed that your code has the comment "To solve issue with _ in DOI". However, that's hugely inefficient. Much better to load the `xurl` package.

Comment: Still, I think it is a good idea to avoid underscores in citation keys and other similar places, such as included file names, if practically possible.

Comment: @MartinBaláž - I heartily agree with the idea that it's useful to avoid using TeX-special characters (such as `_`) *unless* they're used in their TeX-special sense. However, at times one has to collaborate with coauthors who don't share this view, and who may not at all be pleased to be told that they can't use `_` in citation keys just because *you* employ the `underscore` package. Their annoyance will probably rise if and when they realize that the trouble wouldn't even occur if you were using the `xurl` package instead of the `underscore` package, as I recommend you do in my answer.

Comment: @Mico I think that's covered by "if practically possible". Rewriting legacy code or documents is generally a good thing, but one needs to carefully consider if it is really worth the effort. If the problem can be simply avoided by not using a certain expendable package in one document, this is definitely the way to go.